# If $G$ is a group and $H_1\subset H_2$, where $H_1, H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ then what is the relation between $N(H_1)$ and $N(H_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $H_1\subset H_2$, where $H_1, H_2$ are subgroups of $G$, then what is the relation between $N(H_1)$ and $N(H_2)$?

Note that $N(H_1)=\{x\in G : xH_1=H_1x\}$ is the $\textbf{normalizer}$ of $H_1$ and similarly, $N(H_2)$ is the $\textbf{normalizer}$ of $H_2$.

Here's my answer: $x\in N(H_1) \Rightarrow xH_1=H_1x \Rightarrow xH_2=H_2x \Rightarrow x\in N(H_2)$ which implies $N(H_1)\subset N(H_2)$.

However, I am not sure if my logic is correct. Something tells me it is otherway, ie $N(H_2)\subset N(H_1)$.
Please confirm whether this is correct.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any particular relationship between them. What makes you think that there might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is not correct. You cannot go from $xH_1=H_1x$ to $xH_2=H_2x$; there simply is no warrant for that assertion.

In fact, there need not be any relation between the two normalizers. You can have equality, you can have either properly contained in the other, or you can have them be incomparable. Here are examples:

1. **Equality:** if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are both normal (e.g., if $G$ is abelian), then $N_G(H_1)=N_G(H_2)$.
2. **Normalizer of $H_1$ is properly contained in the normalizer of $H_2$**. This can happen if for example $H_2$ is normal but $H_1$ is not normal. For example, in the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, with $p$ odd,
   $$G = \langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^p=e, yx=xyz, xz=zx, yz=zy\rangle,$$
   we can take $H_1=\langle x\rangle$ and $H_2=\langle x,z\rangle$. Then $H_2$ has index $p$, so it is normal, hence $N_G(H_2) = G$; but $H_1$ is not normal, since $yxy^{-1} = xz\notin\langle x\rangle$; in fact, $N_G(H_1)=H_1$. So here $N_G(H_1)\subsetneq N_G(H_2)$.
3. **Normalizer of $H_2$ is properly contained in the normalizer of $H_1$**. This can happen if $H_1$ is normal but $H_2$ is not. For example, take again the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$ with $p$ odd, let $H_1=\{e\}$, and $H_2=\langle x\rangle$. Then $N_G(H_2)=H_2\subsetneq G = N_G(H_1)$.
4. **Normalizers are incomparable.** In $G=S_5$, take $H_1=\{e,(12)\}$, and take $H_2 = \{e, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$. Note that $(13)(24)\in N_G(H_2)$ but $(13)(24)$ does not normalize $H_1$; so $N_G(H_2)$ is not contained in $N_G(H_1)$. On the other hand, $(45)$ normalizes $H_1$, but does not normalize $H_2$, so $N_G(H_1)$ is not contained in $N_G(H_2)$. Thus, the normalizers are incomparable: neither contains the other.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It seemed it was just a question of which set is contained in the other. But using the definition of normalizer, the above scenarios play out. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the normalizer of $\{e\}$ is $G$ and the normalizer of $G$ is also $G$ any result in that vein would give us the normalizer of any subgroup is also $G$.

Comment: Answer seems vague but is in the right direction.

Comment: @John: Not at all; he is pointing out that if your claimed inclusion held, every subgroup of every group would necessarily be normal... which is a clear indication the inclusion you claimed cannot possibly always hold.